# operator overloading in c++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

suppose i have 2 objects of a class  and it has one int data member.
i want to add those integer data to other object and store the output in the first obj's data member.I can overload the + operator and use the statement like below

```
X+Y  //where X and Y are objects of one class.
```

if i have to add like below

```
X+10// here i want to add 10 to the data member of X.
```

for above also i can overload the operator `+`.

but if i have `10+X` and i want to add 10 to the data member of `X` how could i do it?

Comment: You need a global function `operator+` with two arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The same way:

```
MyClass operator+(MyClass const& lhs, MyClass const& rhs);
MyClass operator+(MyClass const& lhs, int rhs);
MyClass operator+(int lhs, MyClass const& rhs);
```

(`operator+` should not normally be a member.)

If you overload `operator+`, you'll also want to `overload +=`.  One
frequent idiom involved implementing + in terms of +=.  This can
be more or less automated (if you have a lot of classes
supporting operators) by defining something like:

```
template<typename DerivedType>
class ArithmeticOperators
{
  public:
    friend DerivedType operator+(
        DerivedType const&  lhs,
        DerivedType const&  rhs)
    {
        DerivedType         result(lhs);
        result += rhs;
        return result;
    }
    //  And so on for the other operators...
protected:
    ~ArithmeticOperators() {}
};

template<typename DerivedType, typename OtherType>
class MixedArithmeticOperators
{
  public:
    friend DerivedType operator+(
        DerivedType const&  lhs,
        OtherType const&    rhs)
    {
        DerivedType         result(lhs);
        result += rhs;
        return result;
    }
    friend DerivedType operator+(
        OtherType const&    lhs,
        DerivedType const&  rhs)
    {
        DerivedType         result(rhs);
        result += lsh;
        return result;
    }
    //  And so on: non-commutative operators only have the
    //  first.
protected:
    ~MixedArithmeticOperators() {}
};
```

, then deriving from whatever is needed: in your case:

```
class MyClass : public ArithmeticOperators<MyClass>,
                MixedArithmeticOperators<MyClass, int>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to create an overloaded operator as a free function with the correct parameter order:

```
// This will match "int + YourClass" additions
YourClass operator+(int Left, const YourClass & Right)
{
    // If your addition operation is commutative, you can just call the other
    // version swapping the arguments, otherwise put here your addition logic
    return Right + Left;
}
```

If the operator needs to fiddle with the internals of your class you can make it `friend`.

---

As others pointed out, there are some best/common practices that you should follow if you implement `operator+`, I suggest you to have a look to the great [C++-FAQ on operator overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading) for more info about them.

Answer (score 1):

Don't overload the operator `+` as a member function of the class.
You can either define a global function `operator +` with two parameters or make `operator +` a friend of your class (In that case you should be having a parameterized constructor to convert `10` to an object of your class-type).

Comment: could you please explain why?

Comment: @zombie : Read this C++-FAQ on operator overloading : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading

Comment: Cause operator overloads as member functions always expect the left class to be your class (e.g. class + 10). While some operations might allow you to swap parameters if you calculate it by hand (addition, multiplikation) the compiler won't be able to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Define a non-member stand-alone free function as:

```
sample operator+(int leftOperand, const sample & rightOperand)
{
   //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should define a non-member friend function

```
YourClass operator+(const YourClass &a, const YourClass&b) {

    // do the math here

}
```

it should be friend to get to the private members of `YourClass`. Also you should create constructor for `YourClass` that takes `int`.

In this way you've got one `operator+` and for every other then `int` you just create another constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Although you can do that using a global operator+, I would advise not to do it.

Only use operator overloading for data types for which the operators are immediately clear, e.g.:

- complex numbers
- strings (+,- ok, but * probably doesn't make much sense here)

The risk with overloaded operators is that the compiler may perform unwanted conversions, especially if you didn't make the single-argument constructor explicit.

Comment: What does global have to do with anything? A freestanding operator-function needn't be global

Comment: It is not any more global than a class method.

Comment: My suggestion was not to use operator overloading at all, unless for 'logical' cases (complex numbers, ...).